# phpmailer sending emails to multiple addresses

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm making a mailling list and wanted to send emails to multiple addresses. I have it working but i have a question.
I have an array of emails lets say

```
$emails = array('email1@example.com', 'email2@example.com', 'email3@example.com');
```

now, to send to these 3 emails, what i did was

```
foreach($emails as $email) {
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
}
```

this works but wont this send 3 separate emails? (one for each?)
How can i make it send just one email to all the addresses?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does your `$mail->AddAddress()`?

Answer (score 0):

No. That code *will* send one email to all three addresses, and all addressees will be able to see all the other recipient's addresses. If that's not what you want, look into using `addBCC` instead, or send separate messages, as shown in the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer.